# Adding an AJAX call to this Combobox to read through JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, combobox

I'm having problems adding a XHR request to query JSON to my script, 
I rarely work with either so it's giving me a lot of problems. I know
that I will need to query a JS file, and that I will need to select
from matches in an array, but I am completely stumped on how to do it.
Something else I need to do is count matches each time I fire of a request.

The categories startList is what I am using now, it's not really filled
in but I was just trying to get it to work first before I started using
JSON. Can anyone help me here?

```
var categories = [];

categories["startList"]                 = ["Men","Women"]
    categories["Men"]                   = ["Red","Blue","Multi"];
        categories["Red"]               = ["Leather","Metal","Ceramic","Plastic"];
            categories["Leather"]               = ["",""];
            categories["Metal"]                 = ["",""];
            categories["Ceramic"]               = ["",""];
            categories["Plastic"]               = ["",""];
        categories["Blue"]              = ["This","That","Neither"];
        categories["Multi"]             = ["One","Two","Other"];

    categories["Women"]                 = ["Green","Hot Pink","Multi"];
        categories["Green"]             = ["Them","Those","Moo"];
        categories["Hot Pink"]          = ["The","Quick","Brown"];
        categories["Multi"]             = ["Three","Four","Other"];



var nLists = 6; 

function fillSelect(currCat,currList){
var step = Number(currList.name.replace(/\D/g,""));
for (i=step; i

Here is a quick sample of one of the JSON fields I will want to query.


{
     "idName": "The Time Teller",
     "forGender": "m",
     "caseDiameter": 1.5,
     "caseThickness": 0.5,
     "bandWidth": 0.78,
     "itemWeight": 1.44,{
         "sku": 155320,{    "color1": "white",  "color2": "none", "price": 59.99,
                            "cat": "29400",     "img": "155320-0002-front",

         "sku": 155411,{    "color1": "blue",   "color2": "none", "price": 59.99,
                            "cat": "32579",     "img": "155411-0005-front",

         "sku": 160041,{    "color1": "black",  "color2": "pink", "price": 59.99,
                            "cat": "38404",     "img": "160041-0001-front",
     },
     "specialInformation": [
         {
           "restrictions": "Available for US customers only."
           "detail": "Custom 3 hand Japanese quartz movement.",
           "detail": "100 meter molded polycarbonate case.",
           "detail": "Hardened mineral crystal.",
           "detail": "Locking looper and polycarbonate buckle.",
         },
         {
        "desc": "Nixon's The Time Teller watch keeps it simpleton with hard case and custom molded polyurethane band."'
         }
     ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong JSON data. For example the blocks like

```
{ "color1": "white",  "color2": "none", "price": 59.99,
  "cat": "29400",     "img": "155320-0002-front",
```

should be replaced to

```
{ "color1": "white",  "color2": "none", "price": 59.99,
  "cat": "29400",     "img": "155320-0002-front" },
```

But it in not all errors. I recommend you verify your JSON data in http://www.jsonlint.com/. On http://www.json.org/ you will fnd the description of JSON format.

Here is an example of a possible correct JSON data

```
{
    "idName": "The Time Teller",
    "forGender": "m",
    "caseDiameter": 1.5,
    "caseThickness": 0.5,
    "bandWidth": 0.78,
    "itemWeight": 1.44,
    "items": [
        {
            "color1": "white",
            "color2": "none",
            "price": 59.99,
            "cat": "29400",
            "img": "155320-0002-front",
            "sku": 155411 
        },
        {
            "color1": "blue",
            "color2": "none",
            "price": 59.99,
            "cat": "32579",
            "img": "155411-0005-front",
            "sku": 160041 
        },
        {
            "color1": "black",
            "color2": "pink",
            "price": 59.99,
            "cat": "38404",
            "img": "160041-0001-front",
            "sku": 155320 
        } 
    ],
    "specialInformation": {
        "restrictions": "Available for US customers only.",
        "details": [
            "Custom 3 hand Japanese quartz movement.",
            "100 meter molded polycarbonate case.",
            "Hardened mineral crystal.",
            "Locking looper and polycarbonate buckle." 
        ],
        "desc": "Nixon's The Time Teller watch keeps it simpleton with hard case and custom molded polyurethane band." 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg, it was just an example of what it might look like, the
real issue is trying to access in in an AJAX request.